# What does the EH in EHCache stand for?

Tags: java, ehcache

Just out of idle curiosity and Google didn't give me an answer, but what does the EH stand for in [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It doesn't really stand for anything. It makes the name a **[palindrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome)**, so that "Ehcache" reads the same both backwards and forwards, and also evokes the fact that ehcache relies heavily on doubly-linked lists, a data structure that can be traversed both backwards and forwards.

From the Ehcache user guide:

> Adam Murdoch (an all round top Java coder) came up with the name in a moment of inspiration while we were stuck on the SourceForge project create page. **Ehcache is a palindrome. He thought the name was wicked cool and we agreed.**
>
> The logo is similarly symmetrical, and is evocative of the diagram symbol for a doubly-linked list. That structure lies at the heart of ehcache.